# Tracing sling jsp resolution & use of selectors vs variables

Tags: aem, sling

In adobe AEM (aka cq), for a given url is it possible to see what jsp's are being invoked?

We've got example code, not written by us where 2 sets of 'base' jsp are being matched if a specific selector is present or not - 'm' for mobile.
In the base jsp a variable is then set to flag if a mobile or desktop device is requesting.

From then on no further selectors are used - just checks on the variable to specifically include mobile specific jsp or not.

A different approach from solely using selectors to invoke specific jsp or not.

By having the script resolution traced it helps visualise and debuts, but is this a common pattern for sling based code?

Answer (score 3):

You can see details about the most recent requests in the Web Console, the Recent Requests tab ( `http://localhost:4502/system/console/requests` for a local author instance ).

The output is similar to the one below, and it should give you enough information

```
  0 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
  0 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
  0 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/.edit.html
  0 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
  1 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) TIMER_END{1,ResourceResolution} URI=/.edit.html resolves to Resource=JcrNodeResource, type=sling:redirect, superType=null, path=/
  1 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/', selectorString='edit', extension='html', suffix='null'
  1 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
  1 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=sling:redirect, superType=null, path=/)}
  1 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=sling:redirect, superType=null, path=/)} Using servlet /libs/sling/servlet/default/edit.jsp
  1 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) TIMER_END{0,ServletResolution} URI=/.edit.html handled by Servlet=/libs/sling/servlet/default/edit.jsp
  1 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) LOG Applying Requestfilters
  1 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter
  1 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.explorer.post.POSTServletFilter
  1 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) TIMER_START{/libs/sling/servlet/default/edit.jsp#0}
  3 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) LOG Including resource JcrNodeResource, type=sling:redirect, superType=null, path=/ (SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/', selectorString='head', extension='html', suffix='null')
  3 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=sling:redirect, superType=null, path=/)}
  3 (2013-09-14 21:36:20) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=sling:redirect, superType=null, path=/)} Using servlet /libs/sling/servlet/default/head.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also find out which script or servlet will process a request using the [ServletResolver](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/index.html) service:

```
    Servlet servlet = servletResolver.resolveServlet(slingRequest);
    RequestUtil.getServletName(servlet);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @robert_munteanu showed, the requests tab on the system console is the best place to track the processing of *your* requests.

This is common idiom in Sling applications.  Different JSPs are used for GET/POST requests, requests containing selectors or requests with different extensions.

Take a look at the [Sling Cheatsheet](http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2008/07/cheatsheet.html) to understand how this works at high level, or at the Sling [ScriptSelectionTest](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/servlets/resolver/src/test/java/org/apache/sling/servlets/resolver/internal/helper/ScriptSelectionTest.java) unit test, which explores a broader range of use cases.